# i am having trouble with my VBSscript file and it keeps opening the notepad

Tags: vbscript

I've made a .vbs file to clear the RAM on my computer and it keeps just opening the notepad that i wrote it in. what could i do to fix this error?
I've tried rewriting the file. I have  deleted the file and remade it.
the file says

```
clearmem=space (10902)
```

the encoding is ANSI.

Comment: If you don't show us the code, how are we supposed to tell you what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: i did.. its the "clearmem=space (10902)"

Comment: Did you associate opening `.vbs` files with Notepad?

Comment: It could be that the file you have saved actually has an extension of `.txt` but your Windows settings are hiding that from you. You can make sure that you can see the file extensions by following the instructions at [Show or hide file name extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7).

Comment: my extension is .vbs it still just opens the folder as if i want to edit the file rather than run it.

Comment: How are you trying to run your `.vbs` file?

Comment: i'm double clicking it

Comment: Then it either has a .txt extension or you've somehow associated Notepad with .vbs files. You can test by opening a command prompt, using `cd` to change to your script file's folder, and typing `wscript YourScriptFile.vbs` or `cscript YourScriptFile.vbs` from the command prompt. If it works, it's the file association; if it doesn't, and you get a "file not found" error, it's the wrong extension issue.

Comment: Wait, what? _You are trying to clear RAM using VBScript?_ No, no, no, no... what you are doing is [assigning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z65kc1s(v=vs.84).aspx) [the variable clearmem](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_variables.asp) [the value of 10902 spaces](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_space.asp).

Answer (score 9):

This is just a simple solution but sometimes many of us forgot this.

Please check the "Open With" Option.

1. Right Click on the script file.
2. Click on 'Properties'
3. In General tab, If 'Open With' options shows 'Notepad' then please change it to
   "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host"
4. And now you can see your txt file working as a vbs file

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with checking the program that is associated with the **.vbs** file extension.

To do so, first run the `assoc` command from a command prompt. You should see the following:

```
assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile
```

If you do *not*, you can change the file type association like this:

```
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

Next, check the program that is associated with the `VBSFile` type. You should see this:

```
ftype VBSFile
VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*
```

If you do *not*, you can change the assocation as follows (notice the doubling-up of `%`):

```
ftype VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe "%%1" %%*
```

There is also an alternative association. **WScript.exe** raises a prompt whenever your script echos output. This can get annoying if your script produces a lot of output. If you'd rather have the output go to the screen, you can change your association to **CScript.exe** instead:

```
ftype VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe "%%1" %%*
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 run cmd as administrator and instead of:

```
ftype VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe "%%1" %%*
```

you have to type:

```
ftype VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*
```

You may have to log out and in again for it to work. What does work without re-logging is doing "Open With" on .vbs file and choosing "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host".

Answer (score 0):

Years later - To add, my solution was to change the default value in the registry editor, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.VBE from vbs_auto_file to VBSFile.